# AnyChart Line chart zoom

Tags: java, android, charts, line, anychart

I am working on an Android app and i need to plot some data on line chart. I am using the Anychart https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android. I need to zoom and drag the chart but I don't know how to do it. https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/anychart/sample/charts/LineChartActivity.java here is sample code for the chart.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the library, the Line chart supports xScroller feature. A user can use it to drag the chart and zooming. To enable it simply add the following line to the sample code you provided:

```
cartesian.xScroller(true);
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Is that the best chart library which supports android studio?

Comment: We seek to be the best!